# Seeking explanation on pass-by-value/reference results using static variable

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I was given the following code in a c-like syntax and asked what the value of x would be upon execution of the subroutine f...

```
static int x, z;  
void f ( int y ) {  
    x = 0;  
    if ( y > z ) y = 1;  
    else y = 3;  
};  
void main ( ) {  
    z = 1;  
    x = 2;  
    f(x);  
};
```

a.) If pass-by-value is used.
b.) If pass-by-reference is used.
c.) If pass-by-value/result is used.

I was given the answer 0/3/1 respectively but I don't understand this result. I know pass-by-value means the value is copied and should not be altered, but it that seems like the answer should be 2. I understand why reference works, but then not how value/result is attained to be 1.

What is it that I seem to be not getting?

Comment: You understand that Java only has "pass by value", right?  There's no option to pass by reference, or whatever that third one means.

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Errant tag. This is meant to be a C-like syntax.

Comment: The same is true of C though - although C does let you pass pointers, which works a bit like pass by reference.

Comment: you should care about `static` keyword, this will make `x` value different with your thinking

Comment: I think I get it now. Pass-by-value means that x is independant of y, but that statically whatever happens within the subroutine will change its value. Pass-by-reference means x and y refer to the same position in memory, what becomes of x/y is linked. Pass-by-value/result means that when x and y are separate until the subroutine terminates, then its parameter value is set to whatever the parameter became.